# how to listen network in house with wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark

Since I am trying to send some packets within my home from one PC to another PC , I am writing a program but I think I have a problem. Can you please tell me how I can listen the network within the house ? ( I am using windows )

Thank you all

Comment: Do you need to program one or use an available one like WireShark ?

Comment: Just need to know how I can use wireshark to listen all network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a video series on Wireshark basics, they should help you get started :

[Wireshark basics 1](http://www.securitytube.net/video/11)
[Wireshark basics 2](http://www.securitytube.net/video/12)
[Wireshark basics 3](http://www.securitytube.net/video/13)

There are many other videos on that website about Wireshark (I don't want to spam SO by linking to them)